# How do I get my Installer Application to behave correctly with Windows?

Tags: delphi, installation

I have made a simple installer application in Delphi, nothing fancy. Basically I include files into the Exe, and then extract them to a user specified path.

I stumbled across a problem however, and I have noticed this works with ANY Windows Executable, it does not matter if it is an installer or not.

If an Exe is named, or contains the following words in the filename, "Setup", "Build", "Install" and maybe others, then.. whenever the Application is run and closed, Windows pops up a Product Compatibility Assistant dialog, saying the Application may not have installed correctly.

This is a problem, as even though the Files from my installer have actually extracted, and in my eyes the installer has done its job, Windows is complaining about it.

The only idea I have regarding this, is that Windows must check the filename of the Applications when executed, and in this case has identified it as an Installer. Windows must of then set a flag or something on the System, my Installer must then update this flag to say that the installation was a success?

Windows does not complain about this when debugging from the IDE, so it cannot be code related, it must be the OS - this only happens when launching the Application from Windows, not Delphi.

You can try this easily, either create an Application or rename one as Setup.exe, Run it and then close it - wait a few seconds and the Product Compatibility Assistant Dialog will show.

I don't know where to start investigating how to stop this dialog, or where a setting may be to tell Windows the Installer was completed correctly.

Appreciate your thoughts and solutions thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this happens when your install app does not include an application manifest. When UAC was introduced, MS introduced a heuristic detection for installers and shows the UAC elevation dialog. The heuristic checks for names like setup.exe, install.exe. The simple solution is to include an application manifest. If it is an installer you probably want to use the `requireAdministrator` setting.

The feature is known as Installer Detection and is discussed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/00d04415-2b2f-422c-b70e-b18ff918c281.aspx).

For what it is worth, I would always build an installer with a dedicated install tool like InnoSetup for example.

Comment: That is a very detailed article! I know I could of used InnoSetup or similar, but I wanted to make my own simple installer.

Comment: I also found this useful post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/06/18/pca-changes-for-windows-7-how-to-tell-us-you-are-not-an-installer-take-2-because-we-changed-the-rules-on-you.aspx

Comment: and also this template which I briefly noticed stops the compatibility assistant nagging http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/manifest-template

Comment: I really hope soon Windows blocks any installer that is not written using Windows Installer engine. A lot of troubles under Windows were often due to bad coded installer and uninstallers. InnoSetup is a good tool even if it doesn't use the Windows Installer engine, because it is written by someone who have a very good knowledge about installers, yet I believe an OS should enforce a strict control on what gets installed on it and how. DIY installers are too dangerous today.

Comment: @MadHatter, surely how you distribute your Application is ultimately down to the developer? besides, before I would even consider making an Application public it would have to go through a series of testing, deployment by installation being one of them - Windows blocking custom installations would be a bad thing in my opinion.

Comment: @Craig Windows installer is used to make custom installations. That's not the point. You can install anything with Windows installer. But I would be inclined to let devs choose their own tools, especially since using Windows installer is very challenging.

Comment: It's very funny people think Apple is great when it blocks applications at its sole discretion because it allows for a "safer environment" but Microsoft should not and allows for a lot of bad code to be run on Windows. How you distribute your application should be under OS control. Developer must adhere to the OS specifications. Lots of Windows issues are due to developers ignoring specifications. Windows Installer is a public API, it could be complex but there are tools to make it easier, and should become the only way to install software on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

As David pointed out, MS uses some fuzzy logic to try to guess if the program is an installer. I wouldn't rely on this, as this is only for supporting legacy installer applications.

All new applications should have a [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), specifying whether it requires elevated privileges.

If an application has a manifest file that includes the requestedExecutionLevel directive, then Windows does not attempt [Installer Detection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Any program that is detected as an installer program but does not add a registry entry to the Add Remove Programs section of the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall) will get the message "This program might not have installed correctly".